# incorporate asynchronous javascript post requests into php class file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I've inherited a website with an obscure PHP framework called syndrome for which I can't find any documentation, but the problem I'm trying to solve should be fairly simple for a good PHP developer.

I am trying to make ajax requests from javascript to a php file to execute a particular function. The ajax request is simply:

```
loadNewImage = function(){
        $.ajax({ url: '/app/library/Controller/Reel.php',
             data: {action: 'test'},
             type: 'post',
             success: function(output) {
             alert(output);
         }
    });
}
```

The current PHP file is structured like this:

```
<?php

    class Controller_Reel extends BaseController_Web {

        protected function defaultAction() {
            parent::getPage($this->template, 'home');

            $homepage = Homepage::getInstance()->getHomepage();
            $this->template->title = 'Homepage';
            $this->template->image = $homepage['asset_image'];
            $this->template->center = array('reel');
            $this->setResponse($this->template);
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is add to the file a check for post data. I'm not good with PHP, but I tried:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
    echo 'TEST POST';
}

class Controller_Reel extends BaseController_Web {

    protected function defaultAction() {
        parent::getPage($this->template, 'home');

        $homepage = Homepage::getInstance()->getHomepage();
        $this->template->title = 'Homepage';
        $this->template->image = $homepage['asset_image'];
        $this->template->center = array('reel');
        $this->setResponse($this->template);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that's maybe because the check for post data is not happening within the class itself, but I'm not exactly sure how to structure the code. Can anybody help straighten me out?

---

UPDATE: I found this inside a file called ControllerSite.php -> (of which baseController_Web is extended:

```
protected function respond() {
        switch($this->response_type) {
            case self::RESPONSE_PAGE:
                // always try to make ie use the latest rendering engine
            case self::RESPONSE_TEXT:
                Helper_Request::respond($this->processed_response, Helper_Request::RESPONSE_PRINT, Config::$platform);
                break;
            case self::RESPONSE_JSON:
                Helper_Request::respond($this->processed_response, Helper_Request::RESPONSE_JSON, Config::$platform);
                break;
            case self::RESPONSE_REDIR:
                Helper_Request::respond($this->processed_response, Helper_Request::RESPONSE_REDIR, Config::$platform);
                break;
            case self::RESPONSE_CONTENT:
                // TODO: we'll need to figure the out, but don't need to worry about it for now
                break;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

and then in Controller.php (of which ControllerSite.php is extended), this:

```
final private function execute() {
        $action = $this->getMethodName();
        $is_ajax = Helper_Request::isAjax();
        $data_type = strtolower(Helper_Request::setDefault($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'], ''));
        if($is_ajax && preg_match('/\w+\/json|\w+\/javascript/i', $data_type) && method_exists($this, $action . 'JsonAction')) {
            // it there was a ajax json request and the ajax json specific method exists, execute it
            return $this->{$action . 'JsonAction'}();

}
return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Controller_Reel extends BaseController_Web {

    protected function defaultAction() {
        parent::getPage($this->template, 'home');

        $homepage = Homepage::getInstance()->getHomepage();
        $this->template->title = 'Homepage';
        $this->template->image = $homepage['asset_image'];
        $this->template->center = array('reel');
        if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
            $reponse['success'] = true;
            $response['responseVal'] = 'This is a test';
            $this->setResponse($response);
        } else {
            $this->setResponse($this->template);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck! I get a 500 error. Could be that the response object can't accommodate a simple string maybe...?

Comment: @mheavers: why not trace your 500 error to see what the problem might be? Have a look in your logs to start with.

Comment: @mheavers I have not been able to find any reference to the `syndrome` PHP framework?! Are you sure that's it?

Comment: Yes, it is, but it may have been a proprietary framework that the previous developer was building, and therefore one of  kind.

Comment: In which case you can take a look into the `BaseController_Web` class and examine what kind of things are happening and expectd in `setResponse`

Comment: Sorry =( Updated...I think it has a built in method of handling ajax, I'm just not sure where to make the request to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a class method named testAction:

```
    protected function testAction() {
        parent::getPage($this->template, 'home');

        $homepage = Homepage::getInstance()->getHomepage();
        $this->template->title = 'Homepage';
        $this->template->image = $homepage['asset_image'];
        $this->template->center = array('reel');
        $this->setResponse($this->template);
    }
```

In ajax request you are trying to send action parameter with test value and i suppose it is the framework's duty to call the related method named with 'test' .

This may hep.

Comment: Yeah, I thinnk what I'm stuck on is how to call that method, not what to do inside the method itself.